# Exporting java and spring project in a remote git repo

Tags: java, git, maven, repository

So I am working on a java, spring and maven based project and I have a remote repository where I want to export it. As one can only export the .git projects in git repos, I have no idea how to create them and export the entire folder in the remote repository. Kindly let me know. Thank you for your time. If I have framed the question improperly, just let me know.

Comment: What do you mean you want to "export" it? You want to push your git branch to another repo?

Comment: It is my own remote server and I want to store my project there and want to push the project which I am working on locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different tools to assist you in committing and pushing your project into GIT. If you are using an IDE, it probably has a GIT tool as part of its VCS library. Check out your IDE’s documentation.

If you want to do it from the command line, make sure you have GIT in your path. Then go to your project fold and run the add, commit, and push.

```
git add –all
git commit -am "<commit message>"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `git init --bare` on the target server.

Then do `git remote add <name> <endpoint>` in the client project.

Last but not least: `git push <name> <branch>`

**UPDATE**

SSH is excellent for doing this :)
Suppose your project is called "test", do this:

```
ssh remoteserver
cd /path/to/projects
mkdir test # make a new directory for your project
cd test
git init --bare # creates the git server repo
```

On your client

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@host/path/to/projects/test
git push origin master
```

Comment: Hello Nablex, Thanks for the comment. I dont understand what you mean by name, endpoint here. I am working with a directory here, which has all java, images, xml, etc type of file. Can you please tell me related to a directory. Plus the remote server can only be accessed with ssh.

Comment: Thank you for the update Nablex, I seem a bit closer now. I forgot to mention that my client machine is not on linux but on windows8(Dont ask why), I used a tool which integrates git commands in windows command line. But windows command line doesnt understand ssh. I am right now getting an error ssh : connect to host port 22: bad file number.

Comment: @Kernelfreak Use the official git distribution for Windows from the git homepage. It has everything you need including a bundled bash, GNU core utils and ssh. It really makes working with git under Windows a breeze.